# Is it possible to import big oracle database(600+ GB) to jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, import, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to import a large database to the jupyter notebook? Is it restricted to certain types of database and is it possible to do with oracle database?

Comment: Why do you want to import it and what exactly do you mean by import in the context of jupyter notebook? Can't you simply run a SQL query which gives you a smaller, desired dataset using Pandas to put it into a dataframe?

Comment: As in importing dump file of the database to jupyter notebook. Similarly to when reading csv file from the excel. I'm kinda wondering if its possible to do it with dump file?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to import [600+ GB] to the jupyter notebook?

No. At the moment it seems Jupyter has a maximum limit of 100MB. [Check out the source](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/a97ec9569b1995d8aa3da0a7f499510bffc006a3/tornado/iostream.py#L154).

Notebooks are for sharing analyses and the data to drive them. They are not intended for the sort of heavy duty data crunching suggested by 600GB.

> Is it restricted to certain types of database and is it possible to do with oracle database?

You can do anything with Jupyter that you could do with any other Python tool. So you can use the cx_oracle library to import data into a Pandas dataframe and work with that in Jupyter. The CERN site has some very useful information on working with Oracle, Pandas and Jupyter (and they wrangle huuuuge amounts of data). [Find out more](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2016-06-ipythonjupyter-notebooks-oracle)